# VBA Select Case insert

Tags: vba, excel, select

I am trying to write a select case function that determines the text in column D and the value in cell A2 and dependant upon the text and value respectively, inserts an appropriate value in the column adjacent to the active cell.

Here is what I have so far (obviously this will grow to take into account all the variables in Column D and A2)

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "D:D" Then
       Select Case ActiveCell.TextPart = ""
            Case ActiveCell.TextPart = "Cat I(a)" 
                 And Range("A2").Value = 1: 
                 ActiveCell.Offset (0,1).Insert.Value "1"
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  I'm a VBA Newbie writing code for my Uni Dissertation.

Comment: Does changing the line `Select Case ActiveCell.TextPart = ""` to `Select Case` help? For that matter what is the `TextPart` method? A quick search doesn't seem to turn up anything.

Answer (score 1):

`Select Case ActiveCell.TextPart = ""`

This selects on the *boolean* result of that comparison. As it will be `true` if `TextPart` is empty the subsequent `Case ActiveCell.TextPart = "Cat I(a)"` can never in fact be the "case".

If you want to select on `TextPart`:

```
Select Case ActiveCell.TextPart
    Case "Cat I(a)"
        If Range("A2").Value = 1 then ActiveCell.Offset (0,1).Insert.Value "1"
```